# available stock calculation performance improvement

Tags: mysql

I have a database structure like this:

Table: `purchase_items`:

```
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(110)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| purchase_id         | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id          | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| units               | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table: `sales_items`:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sales_id              | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| purchase_item_id      | bigint(100)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| qty                   | varchar(55)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There is a `sales_return_items`, `purchase_return_items` and `stock_adjustment` table similar to `sales_items`

`purchase_items` table has more than 100k items

`sales_items` table has approx 1.5 million items

`stock_adjustment` table has more than 100k items

I am getting the inventory as following:

```sql
SELECT
    ped.*,
    COALESCE(si.qty, 0) AS sales_qty,
    COALESCE(sri.qty, 0) AS sales_return_qty,
    COALESCE(pri.qty, 0) AS purchase_return_qty,
    COALESCE(adj.qty, 0) AS adjustment_qty
FROM purchase_items ped
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT purchase_item_id, SUM(qty) AS qty 
    FROM sales_items
    GROUP BY purchase_item_id
) si ON si.purchase_item_id = ped.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT purchase_item_id, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM sales_return_item
    GROUP BY purchase_item_id
) sri ON sri.purchase_item_id = ped.id
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT purchase_item_id, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM purchase_return_items
    GROUP BY purchase_item_id
) pri ON pri.purchase_item_id = ped.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT purchase_item_id, SUM(qty) as qty
    FROM adjustment_stock
    GROUP BY purchase_item_id
) adj ON adj.purchase_item_id = ped.id
GROUP BY ped.id;
```

This is working fine with small data. But when the data is increased it shows `request timeout` error. What is the solution for this?

This is `explain select`:

```
+------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type     | table                 | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                              | rows   | Extra                                                           |
+------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY         | ped                   | ALL   | NULL                  | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                             | 111232 | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | <derived2>            | ref   | key0                  | key0             | 9       | ped.id                           |      2 |                                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | <derived3>            | ref   | key0                  | key0             | 9       | ped.id                           |     10 |                                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | <derived4>            | ref   | key0                  | key0             | 9       | ped.id                           |      5 |                                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | <derived5>            | ALL   | NULL                  | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                             | 161674 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    5 | DERIVED         | adjustment_stock      | index | NULL                  | purchase_item_id | 768     | NULL                             | 161674 |                                                 |
|    4 | DERIVED         | purchase_return_items | ALL   | purchase_item_id      | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                             |     50 | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    3 | DERIVED         | sales_return_item     | ALL   | purchase_item_id      | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                             |  32185 | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    2 | LATERAL DERIVED | sales_items           | ref   | purchase_item_id      | purchase_item_id | 8       | ped.id                           |      6 |                                                 |
+------+-----------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 - Ubuntu 20.04
Protocol version: 10
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.3
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring
PHP version: 7.4.3
```

Comment: SELECT batch_no..from sales_items ?? There is no batch_no in the published table definition..

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry that would be `purchase_item_id` instead of batch_no

Comment: does (possibly erroneous) GROUP BY ped.id; mean you have duplicate ped.id in purchase_entry_items?

Comment: no `ped.id` is primary key which is `auto_increment`

Comment: Then the group by serves no purpose..

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it  is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Is `purchase_items` the same as `purchase_entry_items`???

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames yes `purchase_items` the same as `purchase_entry_items`

Comment: @RickJames I have updated the question wht `explain select`

Comment: @HelloWorld - What version of MySQL?  Was "key0" actually "<auto key0>"?  The latter would indicate a newer version wherein subqueries are automatically indexed (at some cost).

Comment: @HelloWorld - I see `batch_no` in the Explain, but not in the query -- what am I missing??

Comment: @RickJames batch_no is purchase_item_id

Comment: @RickJames Mysql version `10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, which however will require a totally different way of storing your data and also a new train of thought.  You may create summary tables for each table which appears in an aggregation subquery.  For example, for the `sales_items` table, create the following table:

```
sales_items_summary (batch_no, qty)
```

Every time you insert a new record into `sales_items`, you can *update* the above table for the appropriate batch number record and increment the quantity.  This way, you maintain the sum of quantities per batch, as you go along.  Now when you need to report, you may join to `sales_items_summary` on the `batch_no`.  The sum of quantities are available without a costly aggregation.

Comment: More on [_Summary Tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)